# permanently removing source control bindings

Tags: .net

im developing web application in visual studio 2008 for the first time..
when i try to open an existing project, its asking me "Do u want to permanently remove source control binding from the project?"
what does it relly mean..
how should i proceed..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

its because your project contains referace to  **Visual Source Safe** so if you are having VSS install in your company/ on your machine just give referace to it .   or if there is no VSS install that just click on yes so its will keep your project out of vss i.e **remove binding of your project**